# How to add react on a single html page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

I have create a simple application in react and i want to use it in my sepreate project. so i have generate a build of react application using.

> npm run build

The build is generated successfully and during build i have copied the main.js file into newly created domain something like

> http://reactbuild.localhost.com/public/build/main.js

In my html page i have include the react library for using react in single page.

```
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://reactbuild.localhost.com/public/build/main.js"></script>
```

After adding the script in html file everything works fine but in console sometime it will not load the data and show some error (A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script) because in react i'm hitting some url and one error is always occur which is

```
Error during service worker registration: DOMException: Only secure origins are allowed.
```

so can u please help me what is the problem in my code and do i need to start the react app using

> npm start

Because currently i'm accessing it using subdomain. so what the correct way of using react lib in single page app.

Comment: service worker registration error must be due to an invalid ssl/https config. It won't affect your application. Whereas the data loading error seems something related to CORS.

Comment: in my local i'm using http and server i'm using https . but the error occur in both local and server

Comment: For finding the error in pwa, you can run `Audit` under chrome dev tools.